# UITableView _tableReloadingSuspendedCount causes crash in iOS 9

Tags: swift, uitableview, ios9.1

Reloading data in UITableView

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

It causes crash with EXC_BAD_ACCESS. I investigated and found out it is due to

Printing description of self.tableView.Some._tableReloadingSuspendedCount:
(int) _tableReloadingSuspendedCount = 1

If _tableReloadingSuspendedCount == 0, crash doesn't exists.

Comment: Where is _tableReloadingSuspendedCount documented? Are you using private API's?

Comment: @fragilecat `_tableReloadingSuspendedCount` is a private variable of `UITable.h` -- I think the key is to investigate what causes the crash...
And for that reason we should ASK the OP to show us some relevant code.

Comment: If _tableReloadingSuspendedCount == 0, crash doesn't exists. -> This statement does not make sense, since you are only checking for equality. Please post your code where you use the tableView.